# How to log response times with Action and Reducer in redux framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I am planning to log the time stamp for the time taking for API calls. So i am using the following module.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/timer-stopwatch
```

I am logging it in action file, but how do i access this object in my reducer when the call gets finished?

```
console.log('response_time :' + stopwatch.ms);

return {
        type:    GET_SEARCH_DATA,
        promise: request.get(API_URL + qs)
    }
```

So in my reducer how can i access the stopwatch object?

```
export default function searchReducer(state = defaultState, action) {


     switch(action.type) {
        case GET_SEARCH_DATA:

          console.log('i want to log the response time here');

          return state;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to implement a middleware? http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Comment: let me check what is that...

Comment: i have middleware applied with promise middleware, how can its going to help?

Comment: I think we can do in action file itself, i am use axios, so i can add a call back and log it there.

Comment: I would recommend putting async calls in saga middleware, then you would just dispatch new action - ex. DATA_SEARCHED, with time that this request took. https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga

Comment: do you have any isomorphic examples for this, because my application is isomorphic react redux

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat this answer so is better if you take a look directly to the answer:

[Redux: Using async middlewares vs dispatching actions on success functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304335/redux-using-async-middlewares-vs-dispatching-actions-on-success-functions?answertab=active#tab-top)

I also had my own middleware to make API calls in my previous project, so I think this a good solution to handle your own API calls and add extra actions.

You can log the timestamp within your middleware, so you can implement it only once.