# How to handle Redux's redux-promise middleware AJAX error in a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-promise

Is the proper place to handle AJAX error at the reducer? (if you use Redux plus the `redux-promise` middleware).

There should be at least 3 types of errors: network error / timeout, data not found, or 500 Internal Server Error. The way I tried to handle it is:

```
  if (action.error) {
    return state;
  }
```

so the whole reducer is:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {

  if (action.error) {
    return state;
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      return [action.payload.data].concat(state);
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Is the above the correct way to handle ***all*** types of error that the AJAX call can have? If not, then what is a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

I. Basic way:

a) Define your action creators:

```
import axios from 'axios';

//Post list
export const FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA';
export const FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_DATA_FAILURE = 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE';

const ROOT_URL = 'foo/bar';
export function fetchPosts() {
  const request = axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${ROOT_URL}/data`,
    headers: []
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA,
    payload: request
  };
}

export function fetchDataSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload: data
  };
}

export function fetchDataFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  };
}
```

b) Define reducers:

```
import { FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCH_DATA_FAILURE } from 'pathToActionTypes';
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  let error;
  switch(action.type) {

  case FETCH_DATA: // start fetching and set fetching = true
    return { ...state, dataObj: {data:[], error: null, fetching: true} }; 
  case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:// return data and set fetching = false
    return { ...state, dataObj: {data: action.payload, error:null, fetching: false} };
  case FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:// return error and set fetching = false
    error = action.payload || {message: action.payload.message}; // message could be provided if network/server down errors
    return { ...state, dataOjb: {data: [], error: error, fetching: false} };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

c) Container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchData, fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataFailure } from 'pathToActionCreators';    
import FooBarComponent from '../components/foo_bar_component';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { 
    fooBar: state.dataObj.data
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => {
      dispatch(fetchData()).then((response) => {
            !response.error ? 
            dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(response.payload.data)) : 
            dispatch(fetchDataFailure(response.payload.data));
          });
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FooBarComponent);
```

II. Advanced way:
Define your middleware yourself as nross83 did here: 
[Redux: Using async middlewares vs dispatching actions on success functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304335/redux-using-async-middlewares-vs-dispatching-actions-on-success-functions)

III. Lazy way: 
use redux-promise-middleware, as it extends FETCH_DATA to FETCH_DATA_PENDING, FETCH_DATA_FULLFILLED, FETCH_DATA_REJECTED internally and externally. Please check out the examples at https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/tree/master/examples

Hope this may help.